# Get MIME type of Node Request.js response in Proxy - Display if image

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request

I’m writing some proxy server code which intercepts a request (originated by a user clicking on a link in a browser window) and forwards the request to a third party fileserver. My code then gets the response and forwards it back to the browser.  Based on the mime type of the file, I would like to handle the file server's response in one of two ways:

1. If the file is an image, I want to send the user to a new page that
   displays the image, or
2. For all other file types, I simply want the browser to handle receiving it (typically a download).

My node stack includes Express+bodyParser, [Request.js](https://github.com/mikeal/request), EJS, and Passport. Here’s the basic proxy code along with some psuedo code that needs a lot of help. (Mia culpa!)

```
app.get('/file', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req,res) {

var filePath = 'https://www.fileserver.com/file'+req.query.fileID,
companyID = etc…,
companyPW = etc…,
fileServerResponse = request.get(filePath).auth(companyID,companyPW,false);

    if ( fileServerResponse.get('Content-type') == 'image/png')   // I will also add other image types
            // Line above yields TypeError: Object #<Request> has no method 'get'
            // Is it because Express and Request.js aren't using compatible response object structures?
        {
        // render the image using an EJS template and insert image using base64-encoding
        res.render( 'imageTemplate', 
                { imageData: new Buffer(fileServerResponse.body).toString('base64') } 
            );
        // During render, EJS will insert data in the imageTemplate HTML using something like:
        // <img src='data:image/png;base64, <%= imageData %>' />
        }

    else    // file is not an image, so let  browser deal with receiving the data
        { 
        fileServerResponse.pipe(res); // forward entire response transparently
            // line above works perfectly and would be fine if I only wanted to provide downloads.
        }   
})
```

I have no control over the file server and the files won't necessarily have a file suffix so that's why I need to get their MIME type.  If there's a better way to do this proxy task (say by temporarily storing the file server's response as a file and inspecting it) I'm all ears.  Also, I have flexibility to add more modules or middleware if that helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a callback to the request function as per it's interface. It is asynchronous and does not return the fileServerResponse as a return value.

```
request.get({
  uri: filePath,
  'auth': {
    'user': companyId,
    'pass': companyPW,
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
}, function (error, fileServerResponse, body) {
   //note that fileServerResponse uses the node core http.IncomingMessage API
   //so the content type is in fileServerResponse.headers['content-type'] 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. That's how I initially had it, but somewhere I saw that synchronous approach. Regardless, of course I want to go async and I added the callback.  Although I can now detect the content-type perfectly with your suggestion, 'fileServerResponse.pipe(res)' no longer works. The browser just sits there waiting.  Same problem when I attempted 'res.send(fileServerResponse)'. Also, my base64 encoding isn't quite right yet, but I'll keep messing with that.

Comment: So you can either read the message, or pipe it, but not both (at least not without some fanciness). There's probably a slick way to transform it while streaming it, but start with just getting it and transforming it and sending it out to the browser which is much easier to debug as a starting point.

Comment: Yeah. I hear you, but I didn't have much luck trying to translate the http fields between RequestJS and Express. It also seems like the data field carries more than just the attachment and it's not clear how to get base64 encoding to target only the attachment part.  So all in all, short of diving deep into the network layer, I may just revert to my initial request/piping approach for all attachment types.  As I re-read RequestJS documentation, it looks like that approach may be non-blocking under the hood, but I'll try to confirm.

Comment: Both express.js and request.js are 100% async and non-blocking, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic) module. It is an async libmagic binding for node.js for detecting content types by data inspection.